# COUNT com condições e seleção sem WHERE no final

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Na minha tabela tenho 3 colunas:

- `id(INT)` de auto incremento
- `tipo(INT)`: os valores são `1` ou `2`
- `id_usuario(INT)`

Preciso de um meio sem o `WHERE` no final para saber se existe um dado específico do usuário, e se existe um dado dele, que exiba o `tipo(INT)` se é `1` ou `2`.

Não posso usar o `WHERE` no final porque estou fazendo uma contagem dos dados juntos. O que eu tenho atualmente:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(IF(tipo = 1, 1, NULL)) AS X, 
COUNT(IF(tipo = 2, 1, NULL)) AS W, 
COUNT() AS y, -->Conte se existe um dado do usuário especifico na tabela.
tipo AS Z     -->Mostrar dado do usuário especifico se é 1 ou 2.
FROM tabela WHERE id='$id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(IF(tipo = 1, 1, NULL)) AS X, 
COUNT(IF(tipo = 2, 1, NULL)) AS W, 
SUM(CASE WHEN id_user = '$id_user' AND tipo = '1' THEN 1 WHEN id_user = '$id_user' AND tipo = '2' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS Y,
FROM curtidas WHERE id_post='$idPost'
```

Depois de alguns teste cheguei a essa solução, e o melhor é que reuni duas coisas em uma, Se não tiver dado aponta 0, se for diferente apresenta se o tipo é 1 ou 2.